# SQL: Using SQL Aliases faster?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently using Eloquent in Laravel in executing queries. I want to know if using Aliases in SQL statements make query more faster?

For example, I have 2 different sql statement but will return the same results. One with alias and one with no alias.

**WITH ALIAS:**

```
User::select('details.address','details.phone','details.other')
      ->join(DB::raw('table_details as details'),'details.details_id','=','user.details_id')->get();
```

**WITHOUT ALIAS:**

```
User::select('table_details.address','table_details.phone','table_details.other')
      ->join('table_details','table_details.details_id','=','user.details_id')->get();
```

Does it make a difference in performance etc.?

Comment: measure measure. measure.

Comment: what do you mean @DanielA.White?

Comment: you have to measure to see what is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure it yourself. Use the query log

```php
DB::enableQueryLog();
# Your queries here
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

The dumped array has all the queries that were done as well as how long it took for each of them.